# Can I set the name of the app to something other than the label of the activity with the intent-filter?

Tags: android, label, intentfilter

I have an app with four activities. I have set the intent-filter on one of them so it will be displayed first to the user when he starts the app. It has a label that says "Add expense".

Now the name under the icon for the app in the phone says "Add expense".

I would like the activities to have their different labels because they are displayed in the menu at the top of each activity and help the user understand what the activity is about. But I want the app name to be something other than the label of the activity with the intent-filter.

Is that possible?

Part of my manifest:

As you can see I've tried to set android:label="@string/app_name" on the application level but that doesn't work. The label on the activity is displayed under the icon anyway.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_money_bag"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
    <activity
        android:name=".AddExpenseActivity"
        android:label="@string/add_expense_header" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ListExpensesActivity"
        android:label="@string/list_expenses_header" >
        </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AddExpenseAccountActivity"
        android:label="@string/add_expense_account_header" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ListExpenseAccountsActivity"
        android:label="@string/list_expense_accounts_header" />
</application>
```

Regards,
Mattias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setTitle(String s) in each activity to change the name that appears in the title bar dynamically. So for you setting it in onCreate to whatever you want might suffice.

```
setTitle("Hello StackOverflow");
```

Comment: I put the Launcher title in the activity with the intent-filter and set the title in onCreate in each Activity. I don't like this way of doing it because I would rather declare the title for each Activity in the manifest than in the code but if it is the only way... Thank you very much Donald for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try giving

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

When the label is specified for the activity then i will be shown with the same label in Launcher

What can u do is give label to intent-filter

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but this is exactly what I didn't want to do because I need different labels for each Activity and yet another one for the Launcher title. This way I have to set the Launcher title in the startup Activity. Thanks anyway!